Matplotlib Colormap Normalization with Midpoint Value for Scatter Plot
I'm creating a scatter plot over a map using Matplotlib and Geopandas in Python, and I'm facing an issue with setting up my colorbar correctly.
I want the maximum colorbar value to be 3.95 (corresponding to dark red), the minimum to be -5.00 (corresponding to dark blue), and the zero value to be white, indicating a midpoint in the data.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import contextily as ctx

# Find the maximum absolute value for the color range to center it at zero
vmax = 5
vmin = -5

# Plotting with smaller points and a red-white-blue color scale centered at zero
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 10))
scatter = ax.scatter(x=results_df.geometry.x, y=results_df.geometry.y,
                     c=results_df['Trend'], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=0.75, cmap='RdBu_r', s=20) 

# Create the colorbar
cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax, ticks=ticks, extend='min')

# Define the format of the tick labels, add a special label for the actual max if it's in the range
tick_labels = [f"{tick:.2f}" if tick != actual_max else f"Max: {tick:.2f}" for tick in ticks]
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(tick_labels)

# Add text for actual min at the bottom of the colorbar
if actual_min < vmin:
    cbar.ax.text(0, -0.1, f"Min: {actual_min:.2f}", va='bottom', ha='center', transform=cbar.ax.transAxes)

# Add a background map
ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs=results_df.crs.to_string(), source=ctx.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)

# Set axis limit to limit the display area
ax.set_xlim([results_df.total_bounds[0], results_df.total_bounds[2]])
ax.set_ylim([results_df.total_bounds[1], results_df.total_bounds[3]])

plt.show()


I've utilized Matplotlib's TwoSlopeNorm to attempt to set the midpoint of the colormap at zero. This is supposed to map the value 0 in my data to the white color in the 'RdBu_r' colormap.
I've explicitly set the vmin, vcenter, and vmax parameters in the TwoSlopeNorm to align the data values with the desired colors on the colormap.
I've checked to make sure that the data does not contain any values outside the range that might be causing the color normalization to skew.

In the image it looks like there might only be a few points >0, as only a handful are red. Almost all of the data points are blue, suggesting that the data is mostly <0. To me it seems like the skew is in the data, rather than a problem with the norm.
Running results_df.Trend.gt(3).value_counts() will tell you how many are clearly red. Does that roughly match with what the figure shows?
If you find that the number of reds is large, it might be that they're being covered up on the plot by the blue points (overplotting), though that seems unlikely.
